# How can we enhance ! in a command as variable?

Tags: bash, function

I want to make a function which would work ith if-else case and adjust commands inside. (actually i want to use !)

---

```
function test_funct(){
cmd="grep thisword file"
[[ $1 == not ]] && cmd="! $cmd"
$cmd
}

test_funct not
```

---

and this comes up:
./test: line 4: !: command not found

any ideas?

Comment: You should avoid `̀test` for your function name, it's a shell builtin.

Comment: You cannot simply use `!` to reverse a grep command, you should use `grep -v` which invert the sens of matching.

Comment: i just care about exit code here.
! grep returns 1 if word exists.
That's good for me.
So, i want ! grep. to work.

Comment: `!` is an operator you can't use this way. If you want to reverse the exit code, you may simply return 1 if command succeed as in `[[ "$1" == "not" ]] && true && echo 1`

Comment: i guess this is ok. Tried if-else with not switch and it does the job also. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing of `!` happens very early in the command line parsing process.
Certainly, it is not executed after "parameter expansions" the "$cmd" expansion.

It is not seen as a negating operator by the shell.

You may get it working as this:

```
function test_funct(){
    cmd="grep thisword file"
    [[ "$1" == "not" ]] && cmd="! $cmd"
    eval "$cmd"
}

test_funct not
```

But using eval (unless you have set each and every part of the evaled string inside the script yourself) is a route to introduce bugs and problems.

In this case where `cmd` contains the string "grep thisword file", this might work. But I can clearly see that your goal is to accept input from an user to pick a file or change the word searched for.

Please do not do that. That is plain wrong.